# How ball sort puzzle works?

Tags: puzzle

Ball sort puzzle is that offline game, there is also another form of this game called water sort puzzle. In the game there are *n* stacks containing different colors of balls. There are 4 balls of each color and in total *4n* balls. Out of that, there are 2 empty stakes provided for the players to sort the balls by their color. In the sorting process several basic principles need to be followed.

1. only top ball of each stake can be removed
2. a ball can be left on another if they are the same color (except the situation that this stake is empty)

I am wondering why there are only two empty stakes provided no matter how many colors of balls are there? Or is there always a solution to the game no matter the value of *n* is large or small?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The question is clear.  Are $2$ empty stakes always sufficient to yield a solution for any $n$?

Comment: Could be helpful to have a picture of the game in the question.

Comment: See: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.GMA.Ball.Sort.Puzzle&hl=en_US&gl=US

Comment: See following questions about the same game: [Is there a strategy to win this "move color" game?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4029286/318073) and [Does Ball Sort Puzzle always have a solution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3699265/318073) and [Algorithm for Liquid sort puzzle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3878125/318073).